# How to pass multiple parameters to DELETE request C# Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, parameters, asp.net-web-api2, http-delete

I need to pass 3 parameters to my API DELETE request. Here is my code what I have try.

TaskModel

```
public class TaskModel
{
    public int DeveloperID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string WorkDate { get; set; }
}
```

This a controller class. called `TaskController`

```
    [Route("api/Task")]
    public void Delete(TaskModel value)
    {
        TaskPersistent tp = new TaskPersistent();
        tp.deleteTask(value);
    }
```

This is `TaskPersistent.class`

```
public void deleteTask(TaskModel task)
{
    try
    {
        string sqlString = "DELETE from devproj WHERE (DeveloperID, ProjectID, WorkDate) =  VALUES ('" + task.DeveloperID + "', '" + task.ProjectID + "', '" + task.WorkDate + "')"; // System.NullReferenceException throw
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        long x = cmd.LastInsertedId;
    }
    catch (MySqlException x)
    {
        int errr = x.Number;

        Console.WriteLine(errr);
    }
}
```

I consume this API using ARC rest client like this,**`http://localhost:2731/api/Task?DeveloperID=1&ProjectID=2&WorkDate="2018-03-14"`**
But when I pass the parameters like this,API thrown exception: `'System.NullReferenceException' in DeleteAPI.dll` (I commented error occurred line in my code). What I did wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You need to consume this API by posting your `TaskModel` as a body for the model binder to work with the way you have your `Delete` controller action set up. Alternatively, change the `Delete` method parameters to `int developerId, int projectId, DateTime workDate`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Can you give me it as a answer.please.

Comment: If your API method is for a delete action, a good practice is to add `[HttpDelete]` as attribute and send DELETE instead GET.

Comment: @User.Anonymous Where I need to put that,before method?

Comment: Yes, between [Route] attribute and method declaration `[Route("api/Task")] [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(TaskModel value)` and so you can call with DELETE verbs instead of GET.

Comment: @User.Anonymous Thank you sir, please give me an answer.

Comment: Please, pay also attention to a possibile Sql Injection problem. Consider cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consume this API by posting your `TaskModel` as a body for the model binder to work with the way you have your `Delete` controller action set up. Alternatively, change the `Delete` method parameters to `int developerId, int projectId, DateTime workDate`.

```
    [Route("api/Task")]
    public void Delete(int developerId, int projectId, DateTime workDate)
    {
        var taskModel = new TaskModel
        {
            DeveloperId = developerId,
            ProjectID = projectId,
            WorkDate = workDate
        };
        TaskPersistent tp = new TaskPersistent();
        tp.deleteTask(taskModel);
    }
```

Comment: I gave a sample code of how to set up the controller to work with the way you are consuming it currently

Comment: Sir I try this, But when I try this,this exception occurred now,
`'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll`

Comment: @Gamma What is the exception you are getting and what is the runtime value now of `sqlString` variable? Please be as thorough as you can so we can help you properly.

Comment: Problem solved sir, I edited my query as User.Anonymous's answer. Thank you very much

Comment: @Gamma no problems, I am happy you have solved your issue

Answer (score 2):

```
string sqlString = "DELETE from devproj WHERE (DeveloperID, ProjectID, WorkDate) =  VALUES ('" + task.DeveloperID + "', '" + task.ProjectID + "', '" + task.WorkDate + "')"; // System.NullReferenceException throw
```

This query don't work.
SQL delete is :

```
string sqlString = $"DELETE from devproj WHERE DeveloperID = {task.DeveloperID} AND ProjectID = {task.ProjectID} AND WorkDate = {task.WorkDate}";
```

And don't forget to check for null value in your model before execute query.